# Whitelist only one GET Parameter

Tags: php, post, get

I am passing `GET` parameter like this:

```
test.php?code=10NE25w4hjjh.
```

How can I kill all other `GET` parameters? e.g. whitelist only 'code' `GET`.

Comment: What does it mean - kill? Just ignore other params

Comment: I didn't get it either, what you want to do exactly?!

Comment: Sorry for the bad explanation. I want to ignore all other `GET` parameters exept 'code'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why would you like to do this? It's much easier to just ignore the rest.

```
if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
    // do something
}
// all code below here is unnecasary 
 else {
   exit; 
}
```

Comment: '10NE25w4hjjh' is not a static value.. I've got 1k of them, so it should not be compared in any way.. I want to ingore all other `GET` parameters exept 'code'. For example `test.php?someOtherParameter=something`, I want to ignore it and show error.

Comment: Edited my answer for you @Edgar. The rest of the parameters is completely ignored as long as you don't handle them in any way

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($_GET['code'] != '10NE25w4hjjh' || count($_GET) > 1)
{
   header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');

   echo 'Operation killed.';
   exit;
}

// Continue
```

The code must be 10NE25w4hjjh and only the GET parameter code is allowed.